# C/C++ ODBC SQLExec gets SQLSTATE 24000 Invalid cursor state

Tags: c++, c, odbc

I'm trying to utilize a reusable prepared statement and fetch 1 row only from DB (SQLMX).
I need help with 2 issues (1 is partially solved):

- 1. Here I know what the problem is, but I don't understand why it is a problem or why the solution is what it is. If I don't call SQLFetch until I get SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND, my 2nd SQLExecute gets SQLCODE 24000. Why does statement handle require me to finish processing whole resultset with SQLFetch until I get SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND? All I want is to SQLFetch once 1 row, and SQLExecute statement with new param. Is there some implicit cursor involved? How to I get rid of the cursor without calling SQLFetch repeatedly? How do I avoid the implicit cursor when I know only 1 row is needed to be returned?
- 2. When in a loop, there is a ~35millisecond delay between each SQLExecute+SQLFetch set. Meanwhile in java JDBC app, same action takes ~16ms. My expectation is for C code is outperform java code by a factor of 5 at least. So where is the slow down/what am I missing?

I am not allowed to post code, but here is the sequence of steps:

- SQLPrepare(hstmt, "select col2 from tab1 where col1=?", SQL_NTS);
- SQLBindParameter for outgoing col1 value.
- SQLBindCol for incoming col2 value.
- Loop:

  - populate col1 host variable.
  - SQLExecute(hstmt);
  - SQLFetch(hstmt); //to get the 1 row
  - SQLFetch(hstmt); //to get SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND to avoid 24000 error on next SQLExecute.
  - repeat.

Would really appreciate if anyone has any insight.

Thank you.

Comment: why are you not allowed to post code?

Answer (score 0):

For 1., I found the correct answer:
In order to reuse a prepared statement, user must finish processing resultcode by calling SQLFetch until SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND, or (the proper way) by calling SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE). SQLFreeStmt will free the implicit cursor associated with latest SQLExecute and make statement available for reuse.